# Randomize a C# Output via the Console application

Tags: c#

I am completely new to C# coding and have been asked to create a simple application by taking an object and randomizing the output. Think of it as a 2D map within the Console Application.

What I have so far is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{        
    List<Position> positions = new List<Position>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Position tempPosition = new Position();
        tempPosition.x = i;
        tempPosition.y = i;
        positions.Add(tempPosition);
    }
}
```

Just not sure how to construct it in a way so that say for example I want to perform a console.writeline after a random number of spaces write an object, then do it again on the next line.

Comment: What is random here?

Comment: Make use of the [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8) class?....

Comment: As said above by @Idle_Mind make use of the Random class - however be aware that it is not truely random. Take a look at this blog post for more info: https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Random

Comment: You want to have random X's and Y's?  The `Random` class should do. E.g. `tempPosition=new Random().Next(100);`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you ommitted all curly brackets in your posted code?

Comment: The randomization would be a predefined object, say for example if I just wanted to have the console.writeline print out "@" or "$" at random locations within the console app.I'm just not sure how to go about utilizing the random class to do that.

Comment: @Rene Vogt, yes, the stackoverflow website complained when I left them in. :)

Comment: @Hapex That's new!

Comment: You can write out your map line by line, or move the cursor around and print anywhere with [Console.SetCursorPosition()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: You should better define what your map should look like.  Do you truly simply want random pieces anywhere?...or do you want some sense of "walls" where pieces connect to other pieces in some way.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Random pieces anywhere within the console essentially.

Comment: The role of that List collection is not obvious.  But you most likely want to *shuffle* it, like you'd do to randomize a deck of cards.  Google "c# shuffle a list" for good hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Random pieces anywhere within the console essentially

Simple example, then:

```
class Program
{

    static Random R = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Position> positions = new List<Position>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Position tempPosition = new Position();
            tempPosition.x = R.Next(Console.WindowWidth);
            tempPosition.y = R.Next(Console.WindowHeight - 1);
            // ... set other properties of tempPosition ...
            positions.Add(tempPosition);
        }


        DrawMap(positions);

        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.WindowHeight - 1);
        Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void DrawMap(List<Position> mapData)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        foreach (Position p in mapData)
        {
            p.Draw();
        }
    }
}

class Position
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public void Draw()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.Write("@");
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, that helps tremendously as I was having a hard time wrapping my head around using this: static Random R = new Random();
 tempPosition.x = R.Next(Console.WindowWidth);
 tempPosition.y = R.Next(Console.WindowHeight - 1)

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, you should use the `Random` class to randomly pick the positions and also whether or not to draw a @ or $ symbol.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Create an instance of the Random class.  We'll use this
        //to generate random numbers.
        Random rnd = new Random();

        //Our list of random positions.
        List<Position> positions = new List<Position>();

        //Create 100 random positions using `Console.WindowWidth` and 
        // `Console.WindowHeight` to pick a random location on the console screen.
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Position tempPosition = new Position();
            tempPosition.X = rnd.Next(Console.WindowWidth);
            tempPosition.Y = rnd.Next(Console.WindowHeight);
            positions.Add(tempPosition);
        }

        //For each of our randomly generated positions
        foreach (Position pos in positions)
        {
            //Move the cursor to that position on the screen
            Console.SetCursorPosition(pos.X, pos.Y);

            //Use the `Random` class again to randomly pick which character
            //to write to the screen.  In this case, each character has about a 
            //50% chance of getting chosen.
            if (rnd.Next(100) >= 50)
            {
                Console.Write("$");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("@");
            }

        }

        //This keeps the program from exiting until we press enter.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```